# Widen strips in Seaborn stripplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

Is there a keyword argument that can be passed to `seaborn.stripplot` so that each strip can be, say 2x wider than it would be by default?

[image]

In one of the example plots in the `stripplot` doc, the points for "tip" are too compact to really be distinguished. The size of each point could be decreased, but this works only up to a point. So it would seem useful if each strip could be widened to fill most of the plot, with bumpers in between each strip.

Comment: Try using `jitter`?

Comment: `jitter` doesn't seem to work for this -- any value over `1` completely explodes the strips so that they're overlapping with each other.

Comment: Something like `jitter=0.45` seems to work for me.

Comment: Ah -- is it possible `jitter` interprets `1` as `True` and just supplies a default? So `jitter=1` isn't actually between `jitter=.95` and `jitter=1.05`?

Comment: Also make sure you have `dodge=False`. Please remember to add the exact code used to your posts. Even when you refer to the docs, these docs will change during the years while your post is meant to stay self-supporting during many years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant parameter is `jitter`:

> `jitter`: Amount of jitter (only along the categorical axis) to apply. This can be useful when you have many points and they overlap, so that it is easier to see the distribution. You can specify the amount of jitter (half the width of the uniform random variable support), or just use `True` for a good default.

Here are some examples of the default, `jitter=0.2`, and `jitter=0.4`:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3)

sns.stripplot(ax=ax1, data=tips)
sns.stripplot(ax=ax2, data=tips, jitter=0.2)
sns.stripplot(ax=ax3, data=tips, jitter=0.4)
```

[image: jitter comparison]